# How can I print somethying that isn't there?

Tags: c#, text, mode

I'm doing a text based game for a school project and I see myself stuck with a quite stupid problem.
The concept is simple, there's a map, a player, some monsters and some items.
For the map data structure I decided to use a 2d array of char's that have a unicode for content.
On top of this, I have a camera, which has a radius. The player never moves on screen, it has a x and y, but what has motion on screen is the camera itself. This works quite fine except when I get to the corners or any outside wall.
I get my camera doing this

```
int size = cameraSize/2;
int top = player.GetY() - size, bottom = player.GetY() + size;
char[,] camera = new char[cameraSize, cameraSize];
Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);

for (int i = top; i < bottom; i++)
{
    for (int j = top; j < bottom; j++)
    {
        camera[i, j] = map.ReMapPosition(i, j);
        Console.Write(camera[i,j]);
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}

Console.SetCursorPosition(cameraSize,cameraSize);
Console.Write(player.GetPlayerChar());
```

My 'cameraSize' is declared on the beginning of the class and is filled when the constructor is called

```
private int cameraSize;
cameraSize = difficulty.GetCameraSize();
```

The class 'difficulty' is irrelevant for my problem.
My problem itself is that I can't make the player positioned on the center when I get to the border walls as there is nothing to get from the array, since these are negative positions.

Comment: Suppose hypothetically there *was* a value at the negative coordinates that you could read without getting an out-of-bounds exception. What would you like that value to be?

Comment: A simple white space would be fine, I would simply need to be able to keep the player centered but also be able to go the corners and close to the walls.

Comment: OK. Next question. Why do you have a `camera` array at all? You write into it, you read out of it, why do you need an array?  Why not just a simple `char` variable?

Comment: To be honest, that's the result of my trying to fix the problem for over two hours...

Comment: OK, then stop and take a step back and re-think the problem rather than trying stuff randomly. You want one behaviour when a coordinate is valid -- fetch the value at that map coordinate -- and a different behaviour if the coordinate is invalid -- fetch a space.  **That's the specification for a method**, so **write that method**.  Or, rather two methods. One should be called `IsValid`, and it should take a coordinate and a map, and return a bool.  The other should be called `GetMapValue`, and it should take a coordinate, a map, and call `IsValid`. Do you see how this will work?

Comment: The lesson here is: when you face a problem, **write down a careful description of the problem**, and think "*could I write a method that solved this problem? What would the inputs and outputs be? What smaller problems would this method have to solve?*"   Keep repeating that process until you have a method small enough that you know how to write it; now you have a tool you can use to solve the larger problems.

Comment: Yes I can see that working, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches to this sort of problem.

1) In your loop, check if a value if out of range and output the value by hand.

2) Wrap your array in a custom class which ignores out of range values.
Something like this:

```
class MyWrapper
{
    private readonly char[,] data;
    public MyWrapper(char[,] data)
    {
        this.data=data;
    }
    private bool InRange(int x, int y)
    {
        return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < data.GetLength(0) && y < data.GetLength(1);
    }
    public char this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        { 
            return InRange(x,y) ? data[x,y] : ' ';
        }
        set
        {
            if(InRange(x,y)) data[x,y] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My recommendation is for set to throw an exception when called on out of range values, but my example swallows the failure instead.

Comment: I like this answer but how do I it this wrapper?

Comment: After running `MyWrapper foo = new MyWrapper(camera);`, replace all instances of `camera[1,2]` with `foo[1,2]`.

Comment: So I tried that, and it compiles fine, but it shows no output whatsoever

Comment: I shared a self-contained example of using this wrapper at https://dotnetfiddle.net/7L8dVi .  I used `~` instead of a space to make the output clearer.

Comment: As an aside, note that my fiddle renders [x,y] a bit of a lie (it should be [y,x]), or the loop should be inverted.  Making this error is mostly fine as long as you're consistent about it, but it tends to make debugging a mild headache later.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have any problems about that cuz I already had inverted it by accident, but since I'm used to it now, it's fine. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

C# can't "retrieve values that aren't there", but you do have a couple options

- Check to see if you are trying to get a negative position, or a position that's too big, and return a space

  Or
- Increase the size of the array by `cameraSize/2` on all sides, which would effectively increase both the width and the height by `cameraSize`, and then make it to where your player can only move around in the coordinates `(cameraSize/2,cameraSize/2)` and `(mapWidth-cameraSize/2,mapHeight-cameraSize/2)`. (`<--` The coordinates might  by (y,x) because of how 2d arrays work and depending on how your code is written). That way, the camera always has a padding around it, so there shouldn't ever be negative indicies

Comment: I did think about your second solution but after I tried to implement I just thought it would be kind of an unclean solution.

Comment: Yeah... I kind of put it there as a last resort. It'd be a big pain and result in very ugly code

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for the tip nonetheless